# Using Set and Unset in one N1QL (Couchbase)

Tags: sql++

I have this Document whwre I need to Unset orderState array and set profileState to "AVAILABLE".

I am trying this N1QL statement but it throws error on END.

```
update ${BUCKET} as b unset b.orderState WHERE b.type = "ao.los:pro" and 
profileInformation.iccid="${ICCID}" and profileInformation.customerId is not 
missing limit 1 END, SET b.profileState="AVAILABLE" END returning *;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE default AS b
SET b.profileState="AVAILABLE" UNSET b.orderState
WHERE b.type = "ao.los:pro"
      AND b.profileInformation.iccid = "ICCID"
      AND b.profileInformation.customerId IS NOT MISSING
LIMIT 1
RETURNING *;
```

The syntax of update: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html